# rake assets:precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rake, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm getting an error when running `rake assets:precompile` on my production server. As far as I can tell, I didn't do anything differently before this happened. Running `rake assets:precompile` on my development machine doesn't yield any errors. I'm not sure how to debug this. Suggestions? I tried running with the `--trace` option, but it didn't really give me any more useful information to point me toward a bug in the code.

```
deploy@example.com:~/www/example.com/app/assets/stylesheets$ rake assets:precompile
(in /home/deploy/www/example.com)
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "...4882640c.png"")": expected "{", was ";background-pos..."
  (in /home/deploy/www/example.com/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/b...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: We'll need to see the segment of CSS referenced in the error above - it looks likely to be a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, so issue is that I am using the exact same CSS files on my development machine and I don't get this error when I run `rake:assets precompile RUBY_ENV=development`.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, is there a gem  in your development section of your Gemfile that could be causing this? E.g. SASS?

Comment: I have `sass-rails` in the assets group along with `twitter-bootstrap-rails`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this. As it turns out, this was a problem with the Twitter bootstrap rails gem I was using. I was using https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails. It turns out this was an error in one of the sheets being imported in the bootstrap_and_overrides.less file. The solution for me was freezing the gem in my Gemfile to version 2.1.7 and dealing with any dependency issues that cropped up afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the application.css file

It says

```
Invalid CSS after "...4882640c.png"")": expected "{", was ";background-pos..."
```

So it looks is where you set a background image.

If you need help to find the error. Post the css file

Answer (score 0):

What Andreas Lyngstad said is mostly right, except when you run precompile on your assets, everything is being added to the application.css file, so the error isn't necessarily in that file, it's just that you have an error somewhere in any of the css files that are getting included in the application.css file. So you'll need to check for that error in all the css files being included, you could do a text search across all your css files and try to find that one line depending on whatever editor your using.

Anyways, hope this helps.